# Duplicate Query Rows

Tags: python

I am trying to get my query rps_table_q_2 to print 3 times(or however many in the for loop) but i am getting duplicate query statements. I have a feeling it has to do with the second FOR loop, but I have no clue how to go about putting it all under ONE for loop.

results :

```
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
```

expected:

```
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}'
```

code:

```
cd = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
cd = cd.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

missing_file_l = []

for amount in amount_ack_missing_l:
    print("AMOUNT" , amount)
    rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' and paymenttotamt = '{amount}' """
    rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()
    for rps in rps_table_results:
        rps_amount_f = str(rps[18]).rstrip('0')
        rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
        rps_amount_l2.append(rps_amount_f)
        missing_file = "Missing filename " + rps[6] + " in the amount of $" + rps_amount_f
        missing_file_l.append(missing_file)
```

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken, I don't think there's really enough info here for people to answer.

Comment: Can you also print  `len(amount_ack_missing_l)` before entering into the loop.